# geom_smooth line color different color than spread

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason, in my graph, the geom_smooth lines are different colors than the shaded area.  I am not sure what caused this.  For example the Retired shaded in blue has a green line and the Unsigned shaded in green has a blue line.  The Active status is correct.

```
qb_height_rating_scat <- ggplot(qb_stats, aes( x = height_in_inches, y = passer_rating, fill = current_status) )

qb_height_rating_scat + geom_point(shape=21, size=2.5) + 
  stat_smooth(method=loess,size=1.2, span=.6, aes (color = current_status)) +
  labs(x = "Height in Inches", y = "Average QB Passer Rating", title = "Average QB Passer Rating to Height Relationship") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: Here is the result of the graph.]

[Here is the csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19G1HQu_ClSOgKwH_bXmTrdPoYpsrJgJ0/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: maybe because you are changing the fill default but not the colour? ie try adding `scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")`

Comment: @user20650 Indeed that's the reason; post as answer?

Comment: That is it, please post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The  issue was that you changed the default `fill` colours, but not the `colour`, em, colours.

Using the `iris` dataset

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) +
            geom_point(shape=21, size=2.5) + 
            stat_smooth(method=loess,size=1.2, span=.6,aes (color=Species)) + 
            scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

So now the `fill` and `colour` aesthetics are mapped to different colour schemes.
Either remove the offending `scale_fill_brewer` or add another in for `colour`

```
p <- p + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```